# ¿Formas de implementar una clase Alloc?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria, contenedores

Los contenedores stl de **C++** utilizan la plantilla Alloc para administrar la memoria. La clase por defecto es std::allocator que tengo entendido utiliza los métodos `::operator new(size)` y `::operator delete(ptr)` para reservar y liberar la memoria.

He leído navegando por internet que podemos usar un memory-pool como alternativa en ciertos casos. ¿En qué consiste esto? ¿De qué otras formas podemos implementar una clase Alloc?

Comment: Si bien el concepto es interesante, la pregunta no se adapta al sitio: no es concreta, es demasiado amplia, y está sujeta a múltiples opiniones. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar un pool no tiene ningún misterio. Lo que sucede en estos casos es que pasas a gestionar directamente la asignación de memoria en vez de delegar en el Sistema Operativo. ¿Cómo se hace eso? Bueno, el caso general no es dificil de explicar:

Haces reservas de memoria lo suficientemente grandes como para poder almacenar en ellas varios elementos. Adicionalmente implementas un mecanismo que permita gestionar dicha memoria (control de memoria ocupada, asignación de memoria libre y liberación de la memoria ocupada).

Una posible implementación:

```
class MemoryPool
{
public:
  MemoryPool(int capacity)
    : capacity_{capacity}
    , data_{new int[capacity]}
    , firstBlockFree_{0}
  {
    std::iota(data_, data_ + capacity_ - 1, 1);
    data_[capacity_ - 1] = -1;
  }

  ~MemoryPool()
  {
    delete[] data_;
  }

  int* New(int value)
  {
    if( firstBlockFree_ == -1 )
      return nullptr;

    int* toReturn = data_ + firstBlockFree_;
    firstBlockFree_ = *toReturn;

    *toReturn = value;
    return toReturn;
  }

  bool Free(int* ptr)
  {
    if( ptr < data_ || ptr >= data_ + capacity_ )
      return false;

    *ptr = firstBlockFree_;
    firstBlockFree_ = ptr - data_;

    return true;
  }

  size_t Size() const
  {
    size_t counter = 0;

    int next = firstBlockFree_;
    while( next != -1 )
    {
      ++counter;
      next = data_[next];
    }

    return capacity_ - counter;
  }

  size_t Capacity() const
  { return capacity_; }

private:
  int capacity_;
  int* data_;
  int firstBlockFree_;
};
```

Este ejemplo, por legibilidad, no usa plantillas. Su funcionamiento es facil de explicar:

Al crear el *pool* se indica el número de elementos a gestionar. El objeto se encarga de hacer la reserva de memoria oportuna. Cada vez que se le pide un nuevo objeto, el *pool* verifica si tiene memoria disponible y, de ser así, devuelve el puntero correspondiente.

Para gestionar la memoria libre sin consumir memoria adicional, el *pool* usa el siguiente *truco*: Cada posición libre almacena el índice de otra posición libre, salvo la última posición libre, cuyo valor será -1. Usa la variable `firstBlockFree_` para conocer la primera posición libre. Cada vez que se pide un nuevo objeto basta con actualizar `firstBlockFree_` para que apunte al siguiente índice libre. Cuando se libera memoria, el nodo recién liberado se pone en primera posición (será el primero en ser usado en una nueva reserva).

En líneas generales esto es lo que hace un *pool* de memoria. Su comportamiento básico se basa en reducir el número de `new`s y `delete`s que se hacen en el sistema, ya sea porque dichas llamadas son demasiado lentas (en el caso de objetos pequeños) o para intentar reducir un poco la fragmentación de la memoria.

Ahora bien, no conviene agobiarse con ello ya que, salvo que la situación lo justifique, lo más razonable es dejar que sea el propio Sistema Operativo el que se encargue de gestionar la memoria. Es bastante probable que un sistema que lleva en desarrollo varias décadas y por el que ha pasado gente bastante inteligente sepa gestionar la memoria mejor que nosotros. Gestionar nosotros mismos la memoria no es algo baladí y es muy muy muy muy, pero que muy muy facil meter la pata o conseguir un rendimiento peor que si no hubiésemos hecho nada de esto.

Posibles mejoras:

- La clase del ejemplo no contempla *double delete*. Si eso sucede el *pool* se comportará de forma errática a partir de ese momento.
- En vez de reservar toda la memoria de golpe se podrían ir reservando bloques según vayan creciendo las necesidades
- Esta clase no es capaz de gestionar objetos de diferentes tamaños.

Puedes ver la clase funcioando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lmvMjTn8ryASzN9J)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. ¿El resto de métodos son variaciones de esto?

Comment: @HectorGalbisSanchis un pool es un gestor... las políticas internas que use para realizar su gestión pueden ser de lo más variopintas. yo no me preocuparía demasiado por eso hasta que te encuentres con una situación en la que realmente lo necesites